# Parsing error when trying to get JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing

I have a web app I'm building using AngularJS. On the table of contents page, I want to display a list of all the articles published. I keep getting this error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson

app.js

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', ['ui.router']);

webApp.controller('TableofContentController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('articles.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.articles = res.data;   
        });
});
```

articles.json

```
{
"articles": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Article Title",
        "categories": [ "category": "1", 
                      "category": "2" ],
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Article Title",
        "categories": [ "category": "1", 
                      "category": "2" ],
    },
    ...etc..
]
}
```

relevant HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TableofContentController">
    <div class="medium-12 columns" role="content">
        <div class="medium-9 columns">
            <article>
                <div class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
                        <a ui-sref="">{{title}}</a>
                        </li>
....etc.....
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this parsing error? I think I have JSON all formatted correctly, but I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Run your json through a json validator. It will show you where it isn't right

Answer (score 0):

This section

```
 "categories": [ "category": "1", 
                  "category": "2" ],
```

should be an array of objects I think, like this

```
 "categories": [ {"category": "1"}, 
                  {"category": "2"} ],
```

Syntax checking tools like jshint can be very helpful in finding problems like this